# How to fetch documents in firestore with below data structure?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, collections, google-cloud-firestore

i am stuck with the data structure fetching in firestore. I am able to satisfy #1 requirement only. Please help me for this.

Requirements:

1. Show latest k posts irrespective of any users (latest k posts across whole db)
2. Show posts corresponding to multiple users (posts corresponding to user i am following)

Below are the two data structures i could think of, but still unable to fulfill the 2nd requirement.

## Data Structure1:

```
/posts/{postId}/
               -authorId          //one among /users/{userId}
               -message
               -date 
/users/{userId}/
               -name
               -etc...
```

Req1: Show latest k posts irrespective of any users

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

// code to fetch latest k posts
this.afs.collection("posts").ref
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .limit(k)
        .get().then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(postDoc => {
                   console.log(postDoc.data());
                   // rest of the code
              });
        });
```

Req2: Show posts corresponding to multiple users
Issue: In the above code, if i add a "where" method, it can filter only for one authorId, not for multiple.
e.g.

```
this.afs.collection("posts").ref
        .where("authorId" == "xyz...")
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .limit(k)
```

## Data Structure2:

```
/users/{userId}/
               -name
               -etc...
               /posts/{postId}/      (collection inside user document)
                               -message
                               -date
```

Not sure, but i think data structure would be more efficient than data structure1 because when looking for the posts corresponding to users i am following, there's no need to search the entire posts collection, rather just look into the post collection of the users you're following.
Issue: how to get the latest k posts in the above data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You should not hesitate to maintain **the two data structures** in your database. This is quite a classic approach in NoSQL databases called "denormalization" (by opposition to the well-known SQL DBs normalization).

Have a look at this [article](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) which explains "Data modeling techniques" for NoSQL databases and says "Denormalization can be defined as the copying of the same data into multiple documents or tables **in order to simplify/optimize query processing** or **to fit the user’s data into a particular data model**".

The drawback is that you have to maintain your two structures in sync, but this can easily be done with **Batched Writes** in Firestore, see the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes